# Install HP Scanjet Software after previous install was deleted

Tags: scanner

I am using an HP Scanjet G2410 scanner and previously installed the software on my external hard disk. The external hard disk stopped working and the software got deleted.

I used Revo Uninstaller to uninstall the Registry Keys and remaining files. For three other software(s), I located the registry keys and deleted them. Now, when I try to install the software again, I find it telling that three software(s) are installed (not what I deleted the registry keys for). I need all the software installed for the scanner to work properly. The software(s) are not seen in Revo Uninstaller now.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: use /force to force tr installer to install the application

Comment: @Ramhound Could you please give a clarification?

Comment: I Just did a google search since I am to lazy to fully explain it http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/227091

Comment: @Ramhound I think I cannot use your method because as far as I can figure out, the installer is either Install Shield or NullSoft. Also, your link is to a Win 2000 article. Also, the installer is a single 155mb .exe and all the software is contained within that.

Comment: Did you try it?